# Button pressed return a future builder

Tags: flutter

I have a button and if pressed should return a future builder here is my code.

I already search some examples on the web but no luck, Im new in flutter development and trying to create a simple login with api call.

```
Future<AccessToken>fetchAccessToken() async{final token = await _repository.fetchToKen();
>>return token;
```

}

```
onPressed: () {FutureBuilder<AccessToken>(future:bloc.fetchAccessToken(),builder: (context, snapshot) {if (snapshot.hasError) {return Text('Error');} else if (snapshot.hasData) {return Text('data');} else {return `Center`(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);}},);}
```

I want to show a progress indicator while waiting for the api response, but after I receive the response, my builder inside the future builder is not called.

Comment: You can't simply return a widget and place it in the widget tree like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply return a widget and place it in the widget tree like that. Maybe you can use conditional list for hiding and showing the `FutureBuilder` widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ApiWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ApiWidgetState createState() => _ApiWidgetState();
}

class _ApiWidgetState extends State<ApiWidget> {
  Repository _repository = Repository();
  Future<AccessToken> accessTokenFuture;
  bool isButtonPressed = false;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          try {
          isButtonPressed = true;
          accessTokenFuture = fetchAccessToken();
          } catch (_) {
            print('Fetch error');
          }
        });
      }, child: Icon(Icons.add),),
        if(isButtonPressed)
        FutureBuilder<AccessToken>(
      future: bloc.fetchAccessToken(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error');
        }
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[Text(snapshot.data)],
        );
      },
    ),
    ],);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Im currently using a stateless widget on my login form right now, do I need to change it to state full? I tried to run your code but i has error in ** if(isButtonPressed)**

Comment: It depensd. In my code snippet, basically I'm calling the fetchAccessToken in the button and call setState to change the isButtonPressed parameter. This way framework will schedule a rebuild with the new value of isButtonPressed, which mean it will be true and my Futurebuilder will be in the Column widget. I'm using conditionals in list for this and you have to run at least Dart 2.3 to use this feature of Dartlang.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(children: <Widget>[
  FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      try {
      isLoading = true;
      accessTokenFuture = await fetchAccessToken();
      isLoading = false;
      } catch (_) {
        isLoading = false;
        print('Fetch error');
      }
    });
  }, child: Icon(Icons.add),),
    _buildAsyncInfo(),
],);
}

Widget _buildAsyncInfo() {
 return isLoading ? 
    CircularProgressIndicator() :
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[Text(snapshot.data)],
    );
}
```